# Codable extension to CoreLocation classes

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, codable

I need to add `Codable` to two classes. One is `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and the second one `CLCircularRegion`.

I have no issue with `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and it works by doing that:

```
extension CLLocationCoordinate2D: Codable {
    public enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude
        case longitude
    }

    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
        try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
        }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        latitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
        longitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
    }
}
```

But I have a lot of issues trying to do the same thing with `CLCircularRegion`. Since `radius` and `center` are read-only properties I cannot really create them in the same way. The other problem is why I was able to create `public init` in `CLLocationCoordinate2D` and for `Codable` extension in `CLCircularRegion` I'm getting error:

[image]

I see the point of public, but required? And of course `required` will fail beacouse it's extension not a class. So one solution for this issue will be create abstraction class that will contain all fields and build region in initializer I know that, but there is any other way to extend `Codable` to existing class that's not support by Apple yet?

Comment: _I need to add Codable to two classes_. The reason why this worked for `CLLocationCoordinate2D` but not `CLCircularRegion` is because `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is a structure not a class. Structs can have initializers in extensions because there is no inheritance. `CLCircularRegion` however is a class. Classes can only have convenience initializers (inits that call `self.init`) in extensions to insure that subclasses are not broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inspired by [Artem answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52354550/2064585) I solved my issue by storing in the object latitude and longitude in `Double` format.
The `CLLocation` is then returned as computed property reading the two stored values:

```
private var latitude: Double = 0.0
private var longitude: Double = 0.0    

var location: CLLocation {
    return CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
}
```

In your case with `CLCircularRegion` you will also need to save `radius` and `center` in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 3):

I moved CLCircularRegion to computed variable, and it automatically works with Codable now:

```
var region: CLCircularRegion { return CLCircularRegion(center: self.coordinates, radius: 10.0, identifier: identifier) }
```